# Why does "remainderBy 0 100" in Elm 0.19 return NaN, not Maybe Int?

Tags: javascript, elm

In JavaScript, `0 % 100` is `0`, but in Elm, the result of the same operation is this.

```
> remainderBy 0 100
NaN : Int
```

I have just thought `remainderBy` function better returns `Maybe Int` like below.

```
> remainderBy 0 100
Nothing : Maybe Int

> remainderBy 6 3
Just 2 : Maybe Int
```

Does Elm have any reason why `remainderBy` returns `NaN`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument for `remainderBy` is the divisor, the opposite of what you expected.  So `remainderBy 0 100` is the same as `100 % 0`

You are dividing by 0, so the result is NaN.

Comment: Thanks! But I also felt that in Elm world, NaN is not welcomed. Why does not Elm wrap it as Maybe?

Comment: The docs include this message:
> Historical Note: The particular details of floats (e.g. NaN) are specified by IEEE 754 which is literally hard-coded into almost all CPUs in the world. That means if you think NaN is weird, you must successfully overtake Intel and AMD with a chip that is not backwards compatible with any widely-used assembly language.